# Is there a modulo operator for real variables in gnuplot?

Tags: operators, gnuplot, modulo

So, `gnuplot` (I use 5.4 patchlevel 8) does not seem to support the modulo operator for real values:

```
gnuplot> a = 5.0 % 2.0
         non-integer operand for %
```

Is there any workaround over this limitation?

Comment: You removed your comment about telling that your actual question is about how to plot a triangle wave? So, problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following or are there other constraints?

```
a = int(5.0) % int(2.0)
```

Check `help int`.

**Addition:**

Ok, so this is the *real* reason of the question...

Some time ago, I tried to plot a few periodic functions. Probably there are different ways using `sin()` or `cos()`, but then you are depending on the setting of `set angle` (`radians|degrees)`.

Below you are not dependent on the angle setting. I guess it should be self-explaining. `A` is amplitude, `T` is period, and `t0` is time offset. If you plot these functions make sure that `set samples` is large enough to get "sharp" edges.

**Script:**

```
### some special functions
reset session

set xrange[-2:2]
set offsets 0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25
set xzeroaxis
set samples 500
set key out
set ytic 1

tri(x,A,T,t0)  = A*(abs(floor((x-t0*T)/T-0.25)-(x-t0*T)/T+0.75)*4-1)    # triangle
rect(x,A,T,t0) = A*sgn( floor((x-t0*T)/T)     -(x-t0*T)/T+0.50)         # rectangle
saw(x,A,T,t0)  = A*   (-floor((x-t0*T)/T-0.50)+(x-t0*T)/T-1.00)*2       # saw tooth

set multiplot layout 3,1

    plot tri(x,1,1,0) lw 2 lc "red" 

    plot rect(x,1,1,0) lw 2 lc "web-green"

    plot saw(x,1,1,0) lw 2 lc "web-blue"

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the definition of a triangle wave function that you link to:

```
T(x) = 2 * abs(x/period - floor(x/period + 0.5))
period = 5

set samples 999
plot T(x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be several definitions of the modulo function. Is the following one using the floor function suitable for your application?

```
mod(x,p) = x - p*floor(x/p)
```

By this definition, if p is negative, the result will also be negative.